# one random number generator vs six

Tags: python, random

In python, I need to simulate 6 dice.

Should I call `random.randint(1,6)` six times or do I need to somehow obtain 6 different random number generating objects, each seeded randomly and then call each of them once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you're making your own online casino, use `random.randint(1,6)` six times. Yes, `random.randint` is pseudo-random, but for all practical purposes each roll will be independent of the previous rolls.